# react how to make SVG container component to manage drawings in low level components

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, reactjs, svg

I start learning React to make visualization application with a large amount of data. Also, this is very first time to create a web-based application. Previously, I also don't have much experience in html, css, javascript, etc.

So far, I could be able to draw something in the following way:

```
...
<svg width={600} height={600}>
   <AnyChart data={data} ... />
   <AxisX ... />
   <AxisY ... />
</svg>
```

Here, I want to make a React component called ChartContainer that will create a svg with given width and height. I want to use the ChartContainer component to manage information that can be shared among AnyChart, AxisX and AxisY components in the future. Then, any drawing will go into the svg. Thus, the code may look like this:

```
...
<ChartContainer width={600} height={600}>
   <AnyChart data={data} ... />
   <AxisX ... />
   <AxisY ... />
</ChartContainer>
...
```

And, ChartContainer contains only render function as following:

```
render() {
   return (
      <svg width={600} height={600}></svg>
   );
}
```

Of course, it didn't show me the correct result. In fact, it didn't draw anything. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Or any reference or tutorial? I searched but so far couldn't find any simple example.

Thanks.

Comment: you're missing `this.props.children` in your container

Comment: Thank you. It helps me to solve my problem after searching with the keyword, 'this.props.children'. This is the web page I referenced: https://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/